# I need help, I'm trying to change the first 2 commas ( , ) of all lines for bar ( / ). In shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep, cut

I need help, I'm trying to change the first 2 commas ( , ) of all lines for bar ( / ). In shell script.

Comment: You first need to read the FAQ on how to ask questions on SO so that you can understand what you mean.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Update your post with more details such as what you have tried and what doesn't work, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to automate the editing of a file in a script, a line editor like `ed` or `ex` is usually the most appropriate choice:

Example:

```
$ cat input.txt
cat,dog,rabbit,parrot
rat,gerbil,hamster,guinea pig
$ printf "%s\n" "g/,.*,/s|,|/|\\" s w | ed -s input.txt
$ cat input.txt
cat/dog/rabbit,parrot
rat/gerbil/hamster,guinea pig
```

or with the editing commands in a heredoc:

```
ed -s input.txt <<'EOF'
g/,.*,/s|,|/|\
s
w
EOF
```

The command

```
g/,.*,/s|,|/|\
s
```

means: For each line with at least two commas, replace the first comma with a slash, and then repeat that substitution (To get the second comma).

`w` writes the changes back to disk.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
# Assuming input is inputfile
# First replace the first comma with forward-slash (bar) ad save
sed 's/,/\//1' inputfile > temp
# Now take the temporary file and do the same (which replaces the 2nd comma)
sed 's/,/\//1' temp > outputfile

#print the result
cat outputfile
```

Example run:

```
mamuns-mac:~ xmrashid$ cat inputfile
a,b,c,d,e
b,d,e,f
mamuns-mac:~ xmrashid$ ./do.sh
a/b/c,d,e
b/d/e,f
mamuns-mac:~ xmrashid$
```

Comment: No need for multiple files.  Just do it twice:  `sed -e 's@,@/@' -e 's@,@/@'`

Comment: awesome, thank you

Comment: No need for `-e`s either, just `sed 's@,@/@;s@,@/@' file`. Good luck to all.